# I can't print something to console in def

Tags: python

I can't print anything in the function defined. What is the solution?

```
import cv2
def ResimFarkBul(Resim1,Resim2):
    Resim2 = cv2.resize(Resim2,(Resim1.shape[1],Resim1.shape[0]))
    Fark_Resim = cv2.absdiff(Resim1,Resim2)
    Fark_Sayı = cv2.countNonZero(Fark_Resim)
    print(Fark_Sayı)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to call the function

Comment: i write ResimFarkBul(Resim1,Resim2) but error is : Resim1 and Resim2 is not defined

Comment: You need to spend some time on a tutorial about python functions and python more generally. You cannot pass arguments to a function that don't exist in your program

Comment: Yes. You're right. Actually I'am watching video and coding this program. In the video there is no problem but I have problem about it. I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call the function after creating it :

what you need is simply call it.

```
 ResimFarkBul(arg1, arg2)
```

## you createed a function with Parameters that means when you call it you need to give it the arguments.

example:

```
    #create function
    def print_something(arg1, arg2):
       print("arg1 =>", arg1)
       print("arg2 =>", arg2)

    # now you need to call it
    print_something("spam", "eggs") # this will print "arg1 => spam", "arg2 => eggs"
   # if you call print_something() you ll get Error because you didnt give any arguments and declared the functions with arguments
```

Comment: thanks but when i write ResimFarkBul(arg1, arg2) error is : arg1 and arg1 and arg2 is not defined actually i write ResimFarkBul(Resim1,Resim2) but error is : Resim1 and Resim2 is not defined

Comment: did you defined what Resim1 and Resim2 are ?

Comment: they are in function do i need to define ? and how can i define ?

Comment: of course you need to define. those are the Basics, i think you need to learn them somewhere else and not here in Stackoverflow because it's more advanced here. I ll put an example for you in the answer you can take a look at it

Comment: @nidhal_on Questions whose answer is a trivial typo should not be answered. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer